# How can I make my HTML table be 100% wide AND have all of its cells only be as wide as their contents?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have this grid:

[image]

If I change the tables width from 100% to auto, table collapses horizontally.

[image]

Which is not desirable. How can I make the table columns (td elements) shrink automatically to fit their content, while at the same time, the table, and tr elements fill the entire space of their parent?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> How can I make the table columns (td elements) shrink automatically to fit their content, while at the same time, the table, and tr elements fill the entire space of their parent?

`<table>` and `<tr>` elements are as wide as the `<td>` elements inside of them. You can’t have every `<td>` be as small as its contents *and* have the table as a whole be as wide as the space available, because the table can only be as wide as the cells inside it.

(i.e. unlike most HTML elements, `<table`> elements can’t be sized independently from their contents.)

You can set one cell to be as wide as possible though, by giving it a width of `100%`:

```
<table style="width: 100%; background: grey; color: white;">
     <tr>
         <td style="background: red;">Content</td>
         <td style="background: green;">Content</td>
         <td style="background: blue; width: 100%;">Content</td>
     </tr>
</table>
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/9bp9g/

Comment: Seems that I have to let my last column eat the available space and push preceding columns to the right. Thanks.

Comment: @Saeed: correct. (Because tables are as wide as the `<td>`s inside of them.) Although most HTML elements can be sized independently of their contents, tables, because of their special layout requirements, cannot.

Answer (score 1):

The width of the `<td>` will be defined by the width of the `<td>` in first `<tr>`.

Otherwise you can use CSS to define rules for `<td>` width like:

```
.myform tr td{padding:0px;margin:0px;}
.myform td{width:200px;}
```

Comment: upvote for good hint, but I don't want to specify a width. I want td elements to _autosize_. :)