# How to make a table with table-cell-widths, which each of them is fit to its content

Tags: css, html-table, internet-explorer-6

I'm impeded by an issue:
In IE6, table-cell doesn't fit to its content.
Though I've been trying to put content into a div/span etc. with correlative properties, the table-cell stretches to have its width greater than its content's.
Anyone give me ideas to solve it?

Comment: Please, please PLEASE. For the sanity of everyone...drop IE6... It's not worth whipping a dead horse!

Comment: @Lee: Yep, that's the polite way to say it.  Or, to put it less diplomatically and more Crockford-ianally, here's a link: http://26.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_l3jxqkYTAF1qz7fybo1_r1_500.jpg

Comment: :( the problem is that decision doesn't belong to me, it belongs to the naive clients, spread-out all over USA !

Comment: Can you clarify with a code example? A table cell with a lot of data increases the size of a table even on Chrome on OS/X.  Does http://jsfiddle.net/CrUJ9/ illustrate the problem you have?

Comment: Sample is simple. Just create a html file with a table having one row. In one cell you can append some short text such as: "aa", in the other one you append "bbbbbbbbb". Then, though trying to apply any style into the table, table-rows, table-cells, it's no way for the FIRST cell to scale down its size to fit "aa" (always longer).

Comment: And please be noticed that I wanna use some dynamic way, not the static ones (using attribute width, for example)

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6663164/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question and the comments correctly, you're looking for a way to make the table cell just barely big enough to fit the content. Your best bet would be javascript that reads the content of each cell and then sets the width.

If you want a pure CSS solution, you should set the width of the cell to something very small - 0.01em for example.  Then, no matter what you put in the cell, it will be totally filled.  See the third table at http://jsfiddle.net/75Pv2/ for an example.